# Gram Matrices Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Show that, even though they may be of different sizes, both Gram matrices $K = A^TA$ and $L = AA^T$ have the same rank.

My attempt:

We have that $K$ and $L$ are Gram matrices so $K = A^TA = (A^TA)^T = AA^T = L$ and by definition we have that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = A^T$.

Comment: $(A^TA)^T= A^T{A^T}^T=A^TA$ it is symmetric, but not the same as $AA^T$

Comment: But I thought if you take the transpose of a transpose you will just have its regular matrix?

Comment: When you take the transpose of a transpose, you do indeed get your regular matrix back. But $A^\mathrm{T}A$ is not the transpose of $AA^\mathrm{T}$. For example, note that $A^\mathrm{T}A$ is $n\times n$ while $AA^\mathrm{T}$ is $m\times m$. Even your question mentions they may have different sizes.

Comment: Can one of you show me how to properly prove this question please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there are two good ways to see this and so I will give two proofs

**1)** If we are given two matrices $A$ and $B$, then the columns of $AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$ and the rows of $AB$ are the linear combinations of the rows of $B$. This follows immediately from block multiplication
$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} A\mathbf{b_1} & \cdots & A\mathbf{b_n}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{a_1}^\mathrm{T}B \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{a_m}^\mathrm{T}B\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf{a_i}$ and $\mathbf{b_i}$ denote the row/column vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively. From this, we can see that the columns of $A^\mathrm{T}A$ are a linear combination of the columns of $A^\mathrm{T}$, i.e. the rows of $A$. Likewise, the columns of $AA^\mathrm{T}$ are a linear combination of the columns of $A$. The row and column rank of a matrix coincide, and from this we can immediately conclude that that the ranks of the two matrices are the same.

**2)** For the second solution, we use a very general and useful trick for showing that a vector is $\mathbf{0}$. Notice that $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \iff \|\mathbf{x}\| = 0$ and $\mathbf{x^Tx}=\mathbf{||x||^2}$. We exploit these facts.

**Lemma:** $\ker(A) = \ker(A^\mathrm{T}A)$

**Proof:** The forward inclusion is easy. If we have
$$A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$
then we immediately have
$$A^\mathrm{T}A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$
so that we have $\ker(A) \subseteq \ker(A^\mathrm{T}A)$. For the backwards inclusion, suppose that we have
$$A^\mathrm{T}A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$
We pre-multiply by $\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}$ to get
$$x^\mathrm{T}A^\mathrm{T}A\mathbf{x} = (A\mathbf{x})^T\cdot(A\mathbf{x}) = \|A\mathbf{x}\|^2 = 0$$
It must follow that $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$. Therefore we also have $\ker(A^\mathrm{T}A) \subseteq \ker(A)$ so that the lemma follows. $\square$

From this, we have $\mathrm{nullity}(A) = \mathrm{nullity}(A^\mathrm{T}A)$ where from the rank-nullity theorem we have $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T}A)$. Applying the same result to $A^\mathrm{T}$ will give you $\mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T}) = \mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T}A)$. The final result follows by noting $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T})$.

If anything is unclear, or if you would like to know the logic behind any of the steps, please do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Superb answer, not sure how you applied the same result to $A^T$ though, because surely then you'd get $AA^T$ which may not be valid

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, you are right. There is a typo in the answer. The lemma allows us to conclude that $\ker A = \ker A^\mathrm{T}A$ as well as $\ker A^\mathrm{T} = \ker AA^\mathrm{T}$. The desired result then follows from rank-nullity and the fact that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T})$

Comment: I am seriously confused. In your second proof: We use the lemma to prove that *ker($A$)=ker($A^TA$)*. This lemma implied that *rank$(A)$=rank $(A^TA)$*. Further, *rank$(A)$=rank$(A^T)$*. This implies that *rank$(A^T)$=rank$(A^TA)$*. Now, mimicking your proof of the lemma, I got *ker$(A^T)$=ker$(AA^T)$*. This would imply that *rank$(A^T)$=rank$(AA^T$*. Hence, combining the result, we conclude that **rank$(A)$=rank$(A^T)$=rank$(A^TA)$=rank$(AA^T)$**. Since your proof is independent of entries of the matrix. Can you explain, what is wrong with the matrix $A^T=(1\enspace i)$? Or with proof?

Comment: @Kumar With complex vectors you need to take the *conjugate* transpose to get the norms right, if you just take the sum of squares it can be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answers from @Euyu !!. I would like to add another way of proof. Assume $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$ is the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). So $A^{T}A=V\Sigma ^{2}V^{T}$ and $AA^{T}=U\Sigma ^{2}U^{T}$ (follows from substituting the SVD). So clearly, the eigen values of the symmetric matrices $AA^{T}$ and $A^{T}A$ are the squares of singular values of $A$. Hence they have same number of non-zero eigen values and hence their rank should be the same.

Comment: Your proof only holds for $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that $A$ is rank one, so it is a column vector. What then is the rank of $AA^T$?
HINT: When the matrix is row reduced, what happens?

Comment: The rank will then be n x n since A is a linearly independent column vector?

Comment: *ONE* column vector that defines an $n \times n$ Gram matrix. Each row is a multiple of... $A_i$ the element of the column $A$ at row $i$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you said there.

Comment: If we are talking one vector at the moment, call it $\vec{a}$. Then the Gram matrix is the $n \times n$ Gram matrix $\vec{a}\vec{a}^T$. Each row is a multiple of the other, correct? Because row $i$ for example is $a_i\vec{a}^T$