# Rank of $A^T A$ where $A$ has a full column rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm having some trouble proving this:
Suppose $A$ is a rectangular $m\times n$ matrix ($m > n$),

**If $A$ has a full column rank  ($\text{r}(A)=n$) then so does $A^TA$ (= it is invertible)**

I read a proof that tries to show that $\mathcal{N}(A)=\{\mathbf 0\}$ implies $\mathcal{N}( A^TA)=\{\mathbf 0\}$, but I can't understand why that is right.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: We use mathjax formatting here. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is the function N?

Comment: Take a look at the top answer to this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215145/rank-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose

Comment: @user297699 Thanks that helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathcal{N}(A^TA)$. Hence $A^TAx=0_{n \times 1}$, thus 
$$
\|Ax\|^2=x^TA^TAx=x^T0_{n \times 1} = 0,
$$
therefore $Ax=0$, thus $x \in \mathcal{N}(A)$, but since $\text{r}(A)=n$ we must have that $\mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$, and then $x=0$. So indeed $\mathcal{N}(A^TA)=\{0\}$, which easily implies that $\text{r}(A^TA)=n$ as wanted.

Comment: I was missing the fact that if a space is contained in {0} then it has to be {0} as well. Thanks.