Find a matrix $A$ with complex entries such that $\operatorname{rank}AA^{t}\neq \operatorname{rank} A.$
This question appeared in TIFR GS2019.
Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix with rank $k$.

If $A$ has real entries, then $AA^{t}$ has rank $k$.
If $A$ has complex entries, then $AA^{t}$ may not have rank $k$.

The first part is answered here.
My question is two-fold:

What is a particular counter-example for part 2?
Why does the proof given for real matrices not hold over complex matrices?


https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215145/715329

For the second question, if you replace $A^T$ with $A^\dagger$, then the proof for real matrices goes through for complex matrices as well.

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has rank $1$, but $AA^t = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0$.
The crucial fact used in the proof for real matrices that fails for complex matrices is that $x^tAA^tx = (A^tx)^t(A^tx) = 0$ implies $A^tx = 0$. This works for real matrices because $x^tx = \|x\|^2$ for real vectors, but for complex vectors, the correct thing should have been $x^\ast x = \|x\|^2$, i.e., instead of just taking transpose, one should take conjugate transpose. And, indeed, the same proof shows $AA^\ast$ has the same rank as $A$.
