# $Im(H^T) \subset Im(H^TH)$ where $ H \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Been having a tough time working on this one. I can easily show the inverse, anyone have ideas on how to show this?

$Im(H^T) \subset Im(H^TH)$ where $H \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A$ be any matrix. How do I prove that $im(A) = im(AA^T )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706242/let-a-be-any-matrix-how-do-i-prove-that-ima-imaat).For $A=H^T$ this yields $im(H^T)=im (H^TH)$.

Comment: $\text{Im} (A^{T} A ) \subset \text{Im } (A^{T} ) $, but it directly follows that $\text{kern} (A^{T}) = \text{kern} (A^{T} A)$ (since $Ax = 0$ implies $A^{T} A x = 0$ implies $x^{T} A^{T} A x = 0$ implies $\|A x\|^{2} = 0$ implies $A x =0$). Thus, $\text{dim Im} (A^{T} A) = \text{dim} (\text{Im} (A^{T}))$, by the rank–nullity theorem. Hence $\text{Im} (A^{T} A ) = \text{Im } (A^{T} ) $ because it is a subspace of the same dimension as the spaces containing him.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yep, that's it. thanks!

Comment: @R.W.Prado, that's pretty much what the other question's answer is - I'm glad we're all on the same page.